# getting an NSException not sure why

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, oop, ipad, ios

so my app is crashing on launch and i am getting this in the console when i run and debug:

```
[Session started at 2010-12-08 20:46:52 -0500.]
2010-12-08 20:46:53.921 WotT-Codename_Savior[64325:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<WotT_Codename_SaviorViewController 0x4b0b380> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key CreateCharacter.'
2010-12-08 20:46:53.924 WotT-Codename_Savior[64325:207] Stack: (
    42190928,
    43348780,
    42190817,
    209120,
    208670,
    5050527,
    41679989,
    5044964,
    5053145,
    3542950,
    3534896,
    3534602,
    10353,
    2918724,
    2922831,
    2948414,
    2929911,
    2961880,
    51183996,
    41470108,
    41466024,
    2920993,
    2954098,
    10244,
    10098
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

i'm kinda new to obj-c and cocoa touch so i don't really know why it's throwing the exception can anyone help decipher this for me?also if you need more code just let me know...i wasn't sure what to post here

Comment: The CreateCharacter key isn't valid for your object, that's why you get the exception.

Comment: i know how to read i just dont understand what is wrong with my code that it's throwing the exception

Comment: Where is the code?  The error is telling you that one of your classes is not KVC compliant, but something is assuming it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a broken connection in interface builder.

Try opening the XIB for WotT_Codename_SaviorViewController and finding something linked to CreateCharacter and I'll bet that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `CreateCharacter` property in your view controller and you should be good.